# jquery how to fix hover show() effect disabled by input field?

Tags: jquery

Pretty simple problem:

I have a form (login/password) placed inside a dropdown menu that only appears when hovering over the icon and form.  Ie, mouseleave and it disappears.  Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.headermenushow').hover(function () {
    $(this).next('.dropmenu').slideDown(50);
  });
  $('.navselector').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.dropmenu').fadeOut(50);
  });
});
```

Straight forward stuff.  The problem is, once I click on the text input field, the script registers this as a mouseleave and the form disappears.  I need the form to stay visible while filling it in!

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you replicate it in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understood having hover & mouseleave events on different classes. However hover binds both mouseenter & mouseleave events ([Refer this](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)). So you need not have a different mouseleave event.

```
$(<Selector>).hover(functionToHandleWhenMouseEnters, 
                             functionToHandleWhenMouseLeaves);
```

I have included a simple example below.

Example: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BC3D/2/))

Html:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <a id="option">Hover menu</a>
    <ul id="dropmenu">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropmenu").hide();
  $("#option").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).next('#dropmenu').slideDown(50);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).next('#dropmenu').slideUp(50); 
        //$(this).next('#dropmenu').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```